# How to add element in this Array?

Tags: php, arrays

Now here's the code:

```
$men = array(
    array('name'=>'NO.1', 'age' => 11),
    array('name'=>'NO.2', 'age' => 22),
    array('name'=>'NO.3', 'age' => 33),
);

$result = array();

echo '<pre>';

foreach($men as $value){
    $result[] = $value;
    $result[]['gender'] = 'M';
}
unset($arr1);

var_dump($result);
```

But seems there's something wrong, what I want to get is...

```
$result = array(
    array('name'=>'NO.1', 'age' => 11, 'gender' => 'M'),
    array('name'=>'NO.2', 'age' => 22, 'gender' => 'M'),
    array('name'=>'NO.3', 'age' => 33, 'gender' => 'M'),
);
```

How should I fix it? Anyone can tell me, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this instead:

```
foreach($men as $value){
    $value['gender'] = 'M';
    $result[] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```php
$men = array(
    array('name'=>'NO.1', 'age' => 11),
    array('name'=>'NO.2', 'age' => 22),
    array('name'=>'NO.3', 'age' => 33),
);

$result = array();

foreach($men as $key=>$value){
    $thisMen = $men[$key];
    $thisMen['gender'] = 'M';
    $result[] = $thisMen;
}

var_dump($result);
```

You could also avoid the extra $thisMen variable by doing something like

```php
for($i=0;$i<count($men);$i++){
    $result[] = $men[$i];
    $result[$i]["gender"] = 'M';
}
```

Or, just reference the original array values and change them, as follows

```php
foreach($men as &$thisMen)
    $thisMen["gender"] = 'M';
```

Shai.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($men as $value){
    $result[] = $value;
    $result['gender'] = 'M';
    $newArray[] = $result;
}
$men = $newArray;
unset($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $men = array(
        array('name'=>'NO.1', 'age' => 11),
        array('name'=>'NO.2', 'age' => 22),
        array('name'=>'NO.3', 'age' => 33),
    );

    $result = array();

    echo '<pre>';

    foreach($men as $value){
        $result[] = array_merge($value, array('gender' => 'M'));
    }
    unset($arr1);
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
foreach($men as $value){
  $result[] = $value;
  $result[]['gender'] = 'M';
}
```

use

```
foreach($men as $value){
  $value['gender'] ='M';
  array_push($result, $value);
}
```

This will loop through each inner arrays, add the `gender` field to each of them and push them to the `$result` array.

With this method, the original `$men` array remains unchanged.

However, if you wish to change the original array as well, you can add an ampersand (`&`) just before the `$value` on the `foreach` loop which will use a reference to the inner arrays over creating a copy. This can be done as follows.

```
foreach($men as &$value){
  $value['gender'] ='M';
  array_push($result, $value);
}
```